# Invalid connection mongo db url on prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

i'm trying to connect into a database and the database url that it's in the .env file is that `DATABASE_URL="mongodb//root:Bambam&xx12@localhost:27017/dataviewer"` but it's allways saying that it's an invalid url, can anybody say what is wrong with my url connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB database connector requires a replica set deployment as described in this [prerequisites](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/mongodb-typescript-mongodb#prerequisites).

You can follow this [guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) to configure replica set deployment in your local MongoDB instance.

The easiest way would be to use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register) as they have a replica set pre-configured.

Comment: i added the connection string from mongodb atlas but still dont work

Comment: DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0.143p2al.mongodb.net/test" that is the db url